# Selenium with Python -- finding element without proper identifiers

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am using selenium with python to write the code. I am looking to pull the information from a text box. The box auto fills as other information is being filled out. Inspecting the box gives the following code:

```
<input type="tel" autocomplete="off" name="amount" step="any" class="form-
control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-not-empty" 
placeholder="" tw-focusable="" show-decimals="$ctrl.showDecimals" tw-number-
input-formatter="" ng-change="$ctrl.changedAmount()" ng-
model="$ctrl.ngModel" ng-disabled="$ctrl.ngDisabled" disabled="disabled" 
style="">
```

The issue is that there is already another input box that has the name "amount", so I can't do a simple selection by name. I am thinking this would require me to use a CSS selector but everything I have tried so far has not worked. Please let me know what I can try.

Comment: Could you provide the code for the similar input box? If they're exactly similar your best bet is probably selecting by XPath.

Comment: Use the Xpath man, thats the way to go.

Comment: are the two input elements with the same name located under different elements?  You can uniquely identify your target by providing a CSS selector or XPath that uniquely identifies the parent as well as your input element

Comment: Did you try my answer? If it was helpful -- check a tick near my answer, please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use CSS or XPath locators.
Its hard to tell how exactly you can find that element since you haven't provided a source of the entire page but here are some tips.
In the worst case when you cant find any combination of attributes that will uniquely identify the element you need to rely on dom nodes hierarchy, i.e. in order to find first input on the following page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Dummy page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="text">
        </p>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

You can use XPath locator that might look similar to this one:

```
//div/div/input
```

But that's the worst case, usually you can use more flexible locators based on element attributes that less likely to be affected by page structure modifications. Let's say each of our inputs from the page above has "name" and "disabled" attributes.

```
<div>
    <div>
        <input name="input1" disabled="" type="text">
    </div>
    <p>
        <input name="input1" disabled="disabled" type="text">
    </p>
    <input name="input2" disabled="" type="text">
</div>
```

Then we can find first input using the following locator:

```
//input[@name="input1" and @disabled=""]
```

Hope that helps.